# Prevent usernames like “user1234“

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

In the last time I had the feeling that more and more new users came put with names like “user1234”. In this cases I suggest them to change the name, but I wonder if we can prevent this and enforce new users to define another name …

Comment: The 'userXXXX' names are set up automatically: you have to actively change them. As such, I doubt there is much to be done.

Comment: I know that they are generated automatically, but I wonder why we don’t enforce other names in the registration process (I guess that this is not only a problem on TeX.SX). So actually I’d vote to change the registration process to get rid of the automatic user names, or at least enforce an alias.

Comment: It seems like none of the new users I asked to change the name, did it …

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We've had a number of questions regarding the enforcement of "policy" about site usage. And, it most cases, such enforcement is really not possible, nor warranted.

We have many users who literally come-and-go after having received help. To them, userXXXX as a username is sufficient, and they don't really care, nor should we. It still represents an identifiable, unique username. It's probably better than requesting a change and the user adopting the vague username Anonymous:

[image]

Users should have the freedom to choose their names and how it's displayed, just like they can their avatars. [Private information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213032/168244) (which includes the user's "real name") is considered private until otherwise designated by the user.

Comment: Tanks! Then I stick to commenting with “pleas change …” :-) btw. I didn’t meant to enforce to use real names, only something that is more recognizable :-)